# Why is my Done key not resigning the keyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextview, swift2

This is probably a simple issue but I have been testing so many different solutions to an issue in this test project and now I cannot get the Done button to resign the keyboard when I am editing my `textView` field.

My code is supposed to move the `textView` from behind the keyboard when the user taps to begin editing. Then, when finished, the user should be able to tap the Done key and hide the keyboard and move the `textView` back to the bottom of the view. In this code, tapping the screen will resign the keyboard and move the `textView` to its original location. The problem is, when I tap Done while editing the `textView`, it inserts a carriage return.

It seems like every other question I have viewed her in SO is for Objective-C. I am using Swift 2. Thank you for you help.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var textViewField: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textViewField.layer.cornerRadius = 10
}

func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) { // became first responder

    //move textView up
    let myScreenRect: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let keyboardHeight : CGFloat = 250

    UIView.beginAnimations( "animateView", context: nil)
    //var movementDuration:NSTimeInterval = 0.35
    var needToMove: CGFloat = 0

    var frame : CGRect = self.view.frame
    if (textView.frame.origin.y + textView.frame.size.height + UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height > (myScreenRect.size.height - keyboardHeight)) {
        needToMove = (textView.frame.origin.y + textView.frame.size.height + UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height) - (myScreenRect.size.height - keyboardHeight);
    }

    frame.origin.y = -needToMove
    self.view.frame = frame
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    //move textfields back down
    UIView.beginAnimations( "animateView", context: nil)
    var frame : CGRect = self.view.frame
    frame.origin.y = 0
    self.view.frame = frame
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}

//function to hide keyboard when Done key tapped for textField
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

//funtion to hide keyboard when screen is tapped
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

}
```

Comment: Text views don't call methods for a UITextFieldDelegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the VC as textview delegate in viewDidLoad and use the 'shouldChangeTextInRange' textview delegate

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textField.delegate = self
    textViewField.layer.cornerRadius = 10
}

func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if(text == "\n") { //return key pressed
         textView.resignFirstResponder()
         return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: The op is using a text view, not text field.

Comment: sorry about that, just edited the code for text view

Comment: Keep in mind that this code won't work if a user pastes multi line text into the text view.

Comment: yep, he wanted the return key to dismiss the keyboard instead of newline